# How can we use ArangoDB with Grails Project

Tags: arangodb

I am having a cluster of Grails based application I am trying to use ArangoDB cant find any drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the drivers for your language / framework, you can always use Foxx on Arango and call it via HTTP or build your own API endpoint in a language / framework that is supported by ArangoDB, but it is recommended you use Foxx.

References:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/foxx/

https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-drivers/